# Error while looping through child of Transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to loop over all children of a transform but I am getting an error.

This is the variable I want to get all the children from:

```
public Transform parentToSearch;
```

Then I dragged in the editor a Transform object from the Hierarchy to the script into `parentToSearch`.

Then later in the script I want to loop over all childs of this Transform:

```
private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (hasDescription == true && clickForDescription == true)
        {
            foreach (GameObject child in parentToSearch)
            {
                if (child.GetComponent<ItemInformation>() != null)
                {
                    ItemInformation iteminformation = child.GetComponent<ItemInformation>();
                    if (child.name == objectHit)
                    {
                        var centeredStyle = GUI.skin.GetStyle("Label");
                        centeredStyle.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperCenter;
                        GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 50, Screen.height / 2 - 25, 100, 50), iteminformation.description, centeredStyle);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The exception is on the line:

```
foreach (GameObject child in parentToSearch)
```

This is the error:

> InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination
>   type

Comment: Very unclear what you expect as result of this code... `Transform` has other transforms as child objects (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `parentToSearch` variable is a type of `Transform` since it is declared as `public Transform parentToSearch;`. It's also an enumerator and when you use it in a `foreach` loop, you are accessing each child item in the array one by one. You must access it as a `Transform` not as a `GameObject`.

Change

```
foreach (GameObject child in parentToSearch)
```

to

```
foreach (Transform child in parentToSearch)
```